# Reverse Merge and svn:mergeinfo

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

We are using SVN to manage a development pipeline, in which we merge changes from the first stage of the development environment into a second-stage branch.  We have created tools that will merge revisions from the first stage into the second stage.

What we want to do is alert users using this tool when there are prior revisions to the files affected by the revisions the tool is moving in the first stage that do not exist in the second stage, in order for them to review potential logical dependencies (regardless of whether these cause a merge-conflict), and determine whether these prior revisions should also then be moved into the second-stage branch.

However, we are running into a problem where revisions that are reverse-merged are showing up as false positives. Here's the scenario

- Alice commits revision 100 to a file to Stage 1.
- Alice realizes they have made a huge mistake and reverse-merges r100 to create r101 for the same file.
- Bob codes a new change r102 to the same file.
- Carl is ready to test Bob's change and wants to pull it into the second-stage. He is alerted that revisions 100 and 101 impact the same program, and should be reviewed for logical dependencies.

According to the SVN Red Book section on [mergeinfo](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.nomergedata):

> **Applying reverse merges to a target's natural history**
>
> Earlier in this chapter (the section called “Undoing Changes”) we discussed how to use svn merge to apply a “reverse patch” as a way of rolling back changes. If this technique is used to undo a change to an object's personal history (e.g., commit r5 to the trunk, then immediately roll back r5 using `svn merge . -c -5`), *this sort of merge doesn't affect the recorded mergeinfo*.

Is there any way to tell that 101 is a reverse merge of 100 in our scenario, and therefore not present it to the user of our tool? We could potentially run an svn diff, but this seems like a lot of overhead - we were hoping to use mergeinfo, but that seems impossible.

Any ideas?

Comment: We had a similar problem, and the best we could do was use our similar tool for merging revisions to create parsable log messages and include that information in them.  Not pretty, but it worked for what we needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given this further thought, and the whole premise seems flawed; our original idea was to discard both the original revision and the subsequent reverse-merge revision from the list of eligible revisions returned by mergeinfo **but** there is no guarantee that the subsequent revision (in which the reverse merge was done) contains **only** the reverse merge - it could well contain additional edits/changes to the file, in which case it would absolutely need to be applied to the branch to avoid problems in cherry picking other revisions. Thanks to all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following policy, the commit message of a pure revert (`svn merge -c -<rev>`) must start with "Reverted: ". We have a fairly strict commit message template and the commit hooks test for this (if your commit message does not conform, your commit is rejected). Of course, this takes discipline...

You can always remove reverts from the `svn:mergeinfo` property (`svn pe svn:mergeinfo`). But this still requires someone to do extra work. We have tasked a *build manager* with just this.

Thirdly, you can couple your SVN commits to a ticket system. In our case, tickets must have reached a certain state before they may be merged. All commits for a ticket are logged in the ticket system. We have some scripts that collect all the commits for a ticket and merges them in bulk. This allows a task-based way of working.

You should pick something that fits your development process. And write some tooling (if necessary) to support that process. Subversion is quite flexible and we have used a handful of scripts to manage this. We even have scripts that generate dependency graphs (with `graphviz`) between tickets/revisions.

I hope this gives some ideas. Sorry for not presenting the silver bullet.

Comment: I do appreciate the suggestions, but want to clarify that revisions currently being reverted aren't in the svn:mergeinfo - I suppose they would be in the mergeinfo of the downstream branch if we had merged the original commit downstream, in which case we would also want to merge the revert.

We are using a ticketing system and tooling, so we can understand the status of the change which was reverted, but I was surprised to find that there was no assist from SVN here - doesn't seem like an outrageous use case to track commits that were reverse merged.

Comment: The simplest way to keep track of revisions to integrate, is to have the two development streams be branches of each other and use `svn:mergeinfo` to keep track of the revisions being merged. SVN's poor understanding of branches and merges makes it particularly suited for *cherry picking* (merging individual revisions). (It is similar to applying patches.) In the second stage branch, use `svn mergeinfo --showrevs eligible <URL to first stage branch>` to check unmerged revisions, and `svn merge -c <rev> <URL to first stage branch>` to merge said revisions.

Comment: yes this is what we do - the issue I am presenting is that revisions that have been reverse merged will always show as eligible revisions to be merged when cherry picking subsequent revisions, and there is no way for the second stage to know which revision is the original and which revision is the reverse merge among multiple revisions to that file, so no way to automate merging in of both for a no-op.